# SVG center align to text

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an inline SVG that I need to include in a label. However, I can't seem to center it's vertical alignment to the text. Any thoughts?

I've added like so:

```
<label for="menu-check-box">More<svg class="more-icon"><use xlink:href="#more-chevron"></use></svg></label>
```

And the styling is:

```
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}

.more-icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  fill: blue;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tnux7pLx/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vertical-align should help:

```
label svg {display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tnux7pLx/2/